# Need help adding multiple DataNodes in pseudo-distributed mode (one machine), using Hadoop-0.18.0

Tags: hadoop, rollback

I am a student, interested in Hadoop and started to explore it recently.
I tried adding an additional DataNode in the `pseudo-distributed` mode but failed.

I am following the Yahoo developer [tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/index.html) and so the version of Hadoop I am using is `hadoop-0.18.0`

I tried to start up using 2 methods I found online:

**Method 1** ([link](http://bigdata.wordpress.com/category/hadoop/hdfs/))

I have a problem with this line

```
bin/hadoop-daemon.sh --script bin/hdfs $1 datanode $DN_CONF_OPTS
```

`--script bin/hdfs` doesn't seem to be valid in the version I am using. I changed it to --config `$HADOOP_HOME/conf2` with all the configuration files in that directory, but when the script is ran it gave the error:

> Usage: Java DataNode [-rollback]

Any idea what does the error mean? The log files are created but DataNode did not start.

**Method 2** ([link](http://search-hadoop.com/m/sApJY1zWgQV/multiple+datanodes/v=threaded))

Basically I duplicated conf folder to `conf2` folder, making necessary changes documented on the website to `hadoop-site.xml` and `hadoop-env.sh`. then I ran the command

```
./hadoop-daemon.sh --config ..../conf2 start datanode
```

it gives the error:

> datanode running as process 4190. stop it first.

So I guess this is the 1st DataNode that was started, and the command failed to start another DataNode.

Is there anything I can do to start additional DataNode in the Yahoo VM Hadoop environment? Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to use multiple VMs rather than having multiple DNs on a single machine. Also, 0.18.0 is quite ancient now. BTW, what's your machine configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop start/stop scripts use `/tmp` as a default directory for storing PIDs of already started daemons. In your situation, when you start second datanode, startup script finds  `/tmp/hadoop-someuser-datanode.pid` file from the first datanode and assumes that the datanode daemon is already started.

- The plain solution is to set `HADOOP_PID_DIR` env variable to something else (but not `/tmp`). Also do not forget to update all network port numbers in `conf2`.
- The smart solution is start a second VM with hadoop environment and join them in a single cluster. It's the way hadoop is intended to use.